# how i use duplicate scene in Unity with different roads or platform color with same prefab using in previous scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use duplicate scene in Unity with different roads or platform color with same prefab use in scene 1 but when i changed color from my duplicate scene colors of materials also changes in previous scene i make duplicate prefabs for this too but nothing work for me?

make zigzag game with differnt scenes

Comment: You must be using the same prefabs in your duplicated scene also just check that up. If you made a duplicated prefab you must use that prefab in your second scene

Comment: You can also use the same prefab but change the color by usinf a script.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using (does it already use nested prefabs) it sounds like what you are changing is the material on the prefab ... by changing the material directly in the prefab everything using that Material will change. You should probably use either a script and set the color on runtime (which creates an material instance which doesn't affect other users of that material) or use a prefab (instance) with a different material on it.

Comment: Complete projects as example , [here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Unity-Dynamic-Prefab)

Comment: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Unity-Dynamic-Prefab

Answer (score 3):

To duplicate the scene in Unity either you follow [this method](http://answers.unity.com/answers/386970/view.html)

> click on the scene name in your PROJECT panel
>
> click on the EDIT menu in the menu bar at the top
>
> select DUPLICATE
>
> you then have to do this ..
>
> click ONCE the "new" scene item you just made in Project Panel. (it
>   should be bright blue) you have to RENAME it. to rename, just click
>   "Return" on your keyboard and watch what happens.
>
> that's it !
>
> Don't forget you will have to draw the new scene (and all scenes) in
>   to your build -- select File -> Build Settings

or

1. Open the scene
2. In Hierarchy right click on top of the scene and click "Save Scene As" and save with the name you want. That is going to open that scene right away in Unity.

Now you have a duplicate scene and both are using the same materials. If you change material's properties that modification is going to happen in both scenes.

The easiest approach is to duplicate the material and so you're going to have two materials, one for each scene. Go to the locations in the new scene where the old material is being used and change to the new material. Then modify the new material.

Answer (score 2):

*For complete project please see the link down below*

I don't know if there is more legit way.

But here is what I do, normally :

1. Create new scene
2. Save it
3. Go to old scene
4. Select all objects (*CTRL+A*)
5. Copy all objects (*CTRL+C*)
6. Go to newly created scene
7. Paste everything (*CTRL+V*)

**Voila.**

*It will copy everything, with transform, value in scripts, everything*

After *derHugo*'s opinion I opened Unity and tried to copy whole scene, but there was no *Copy* item in dropdown menu or anywhere, then I tried to *CTRL+C* and *CTRL+V*, which also didn't worked.

But there is another way I have found, I clicked on *Show in Explorer* and copy paste the scene in *File Manager*, it worked.

If you want to use different color in different scene, then create different material. Now create a script `Util`, list all of them here (better if it is static). Now create another script `Assigner`. Now get *Scene* name using `SceneManagement.Scene.name`, then assign color/material `OnAwake` from that list. If that list isn't static, you have to create an `instance`.

Full project [here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Unity-Dynamic-Prefab)

Comment: Couldn't you just duplicate the entire scene then? (Select the scene in the assets and CTRL+D)

Comment: However it doesn't really address OPs question which is about using different colors/materials in different scenes.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Sorry for me- I couldn't understand you(your last comment)

Comment: The question seems not to be about how to copy a scene but rather how to use different colors/materials on the same prefab in different scenes.

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out, see I have edited the answer. Is it ok now ?